# Debugging firestore network requests from chrome dev tools

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, google-chrome-devtools

Using Angular + Google Cloud Firestore, I was hoping to debug a request fired from a form to make sure it wasn't firing too often. When I go to the Network tab in Chrome dev tools, I see a request going through to `https://firestore.googleapis.com/...`, but the response data is encoded and looks something like this:

```
8
[1,4,7]
```

In my very basic understanding of firestore, I think the requests looks this way because of firestore's use of gRPC under the hood. I come from a REST/JSON background so this is new territory for me. Is there a better way to debug requests like this?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm facing the same issue at the moment. I just want to validate that I'm not making redundant calls.

Comment: Nope, no luck. The closest solution I found was this library, but couldn't get it working: https://github.com/SafetyCulture/grpc-web-devtools.

Comment: Same here...no luck with https://github.com/SafetyCulture/grpc-web-devtools